# XAML Serialization / Type not found - Help needed !

Tags: wpf

```
No matching constructor found on type 'XYZ'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.
```

I serialized a usercontrol. It was giving no error and successfully completed but on Deserialize, i got above exception.

The constructor of type(s) require arguments, it can't be null. So, plz help me to resolve this error.

Comment: do you have any code you can show? also, why are you serializing a UserControl in the first place? you could put any extra resources into a separate assembly and load that instead.

Comment: for avoiding save/load settings, i am serializing control

Comment: plz help me on this message by exception "You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type."

Comment: Sounds like a pretty bloated way to save settings. How about creating a plain data object class for your settings and then serializing that?

Comment: what you said i'm doing like same - first xaml object to text, then other details by xml serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try following the advice of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184560.aspx), which describes in detail how you go about creating custom types that can be (de)serialized with XamlWriter and XamlReader.

You may also want to look at the [explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795382.aspx) of what the Arguments and FactoryMethod directives do.